# Can we define the Functor Category in Haskell (or any other language with a more expressive type system)?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory, haskell

Here I am talking about the Functor category, which is defined as a category whose objects are functors and morphisms are natural transformations.

For reference: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor+category

I was wondering if it is possible to define this in Haskell.

If we define category like this:

```
class Category cat where
   id :: cat a a
   (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

Now how do we define `Functor` as an instance of this, given that `Functor` is itself a typeclass?

### EDIT

I am not tied to the above definition of a Category. I see Edward Kmett represents a `Category` like this:

```
newtype Yoneda (p :: i -> i -> *) (a :: i) (b :: i) = Op { getOp :: p b a }

type family Op (p :: i -> i -> *) :: i -> i -> * where
  Op (Yoneda p) = p
  Op p = Yoneda p

class Vacuous (a :: i)
instance Vacuous a

class Category (p :: i -> i -> *) where
  type Ob p :: i -> Constraint
  type Ob p = Vacuous

  id :: Ob p a => p a a
  (.) :: p b c -> p a b -> p a c
```

I am not looking for Haskell specific implementation, but in any functional language in general.

Comment: Is your question about implementing this in Haskell? If so, it is off-topic here. Otherwise, if you're asking about how to define this concept in (functional) languages in general, this could be on-topic. In that case, it is good to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed Kmett has actually defined this in his Hask library. The trick is to define a natural transformation as a data type and encoding the functors that this natural transformations map, in the type level like this:

```
class (Functor f, Dom f ~ p, Cod f ~ q) => FunctorOf p q f
instance (Functor f, Dom f ~ p, Cod f ~ q) => FunctorOf p q f


data Nat (p :: i -> i -> *) (q :: j -> j -> *) (f :: i -> j) (g :: i -> j) where
  Nat :: ( FunctorOf p q f
         , FunctorOf p q g
         ) => {
           runNat :: forall a. Ob p a => q (f a) (g a)
         } -> Nat p q f g
```

Now he defines the Natural transformation as instances of a Category like this:

```
instance (Category' p, Category' q) => Category' (Nat p q) where
   type Ob (Nat p q) = FunctorOf p q
   id = Nat id1 where
     id1 :: forall f x. (Functor f, Dom f ~ p, Cod f ~ q, Ob p x) => q (f x) (f x)
     id1 = id \\ (ob :: Ob p x :- Ob q (f x))
   observe Nat{} = Dict
   Nat f . Nat g = Nat (f . g)
   unop = getOp
```

All of this can be found here: https://github.com/ekmett/hask/blob/master/src/Hask/Category.hs